# How to show how many active cases per day using a start and end date in excel

Tags: excel, date, visualization

I have a spreadsheet that tracks when I receive a job and when I finish the job, so my input data is a start and end date for each job. I want to create a line graph that shows the changes in how many active jobs there are per day since I started working. For example, if I got a job in on 4/1/2023 and it was completed on 6/1/2023, I want it to be counted for each day between the start and end. Additionally I want the count data for dates even if no jobs were added or completed that day, ie no actual data for that day in my original data base. Here is a sample of my origin data base:
[Origin data base](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTfku.png)
PST SHE Date is my start date, To CM Date is my end date, and PST ID is my unique identifier

I tried creating a new tab with a column B containing all of the dates starting from my first start date till like 2025 and using countif logic:

=COUNTIF('SHE Tracker'!S:S,AND(cpd!B4>='SHE Tracker'!R:R,cpd!B4<='SHE Tracker'!N:N))

SHE Tracker is the original data base that I have with column r being the start date and column N being the end date. I am trying to return true if the date in column B of the new chart is greater than the start date (B4>='SHE Tracker'!R:R) and less than or equal to the end date (B4<='SHE Tracker'!N:N).... this did not yield results.

Additionally, I created a table that cross references the unique identifier for each case with every date and returns true or false if the case was active that day by comparing the start and end date to the individual daily date, and then I used countif to return all of the TRUE results which did return to me data that I could then turn into a line graph showing what I want. However, this is not an automatic or dynamic solution and if I wanted to get this data again I would have to go through the tedious process once again. Here is a sample of the table and my end desired result:
[image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsCvg.png)
[image of desired line graph result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1stF3.png)

The first column is the unique identifier and then the second two columns are the start and end dates obtained through vlook up from my main database. The rest of the columns correspond to each day since I started work until today and the true false values come from the if logic reference. The row above the dates is where I stored my count data.

I can imagine that there is some way to create a separate table that will take the number of days for completion and add one to the start date each day until the end date to create individual data points but hoping there is something less tedious that would yield the same results using the original data. Any pivot table wizzes out there?

Comment: What has `'SHE Tracker'!S:S` got to do with it? Try something like `=SUMPRODUCT(B4>='SHE Tracker'!R:R,B4<='SHE Tracker'!N:N)'.

Comment: The she tracker is just the range I want to count. Also I tried sum product and it returned zero for everything.

Comment: Why don't you share the screenshots showing the row and column headings, also showing the desired result?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by row and column headings but added some pics

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

| Start | End |  | Date | Active jobs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2023 | 02/03/2023 |  | 12/05/2023 | =COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&D2,B:B,">="&D2)+COUNTIFS(A:A,"<="&D2,B:B,"=") |
| 01/01/2023 |  |  |  |  |
| 02/05/2023 | 28/07/2023 |  |  |  |
| 18/01/2023 | 13/06/2023 |  |  |  |

In your specific case the formula would most likely be this one:

```
=COUNTIFS('SHE Tracker'!R:R,"<="&cpd!B4,'SHE Tracker'!N:N,">="&cpd!B4)+COUNTIFS('SHE Tracker'!R:R,"<="&cpd!B4,'SHE Tracker'!N:N,"=")
```

The first `COUNTIFS` checks for the completed jobs active in the specified date. The second one checks for the uncompleted job (therefore no ending specified, therefore blank cell) active in the specified date.

Comment: No dice, returns four for everything for some reason.

Comment: Ups. Probably because i missed the `cpd!` in `cpd!B4`. Formula edited. Any improvements?

Comment: Alas that did not yield different results. I divided the two countif statements into their own columns and the first countif returned 0 for all and the second returned 4 for all. The logic makes sense but idk why it isnt working

Comment: may I ask why you had to format the criteria as "<="& cpd!B4?, like why did the less than logic have to be in quotations and why the &?

Comment: That's how you tell Excel to search for any cell in the previously specified range what specific you need. The minor or equal have to be put in quotation so it will read it as a text, the B4 contains the date of reference, the commercial and is to join the strings. Reporting it all as a text the COUNTIFS then can use it as a instruction to search for any date minor or equal the current value specified in B4.

Comment: Have you tried to copy the table in a new sheet (mind the date format)? Is it working? It might be easier for you to recreate the formula you need from the example. Otherwise any debugging on my side will need a small complete dataset in order to test it properly. You can use [this](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables#) to report a little fake dataset.

Comment: I would move this to chat if I could but alas. Okay that equation did work to cut out the middle man of doing all the true false logic seen in the second image but I'll need to play around to see if it can be more functional. Thank you!

Comment: Considering that you need at least 2 columns (or rows) of data to create a graph, i don't see a way to reduce it further. You'll need one column for the dates and one for the count.